# Turning Off Calculations in Excel Macro Not Working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large spreadsheet where calculations need to be set to automatic. I am trying to use the code below to create a sheet in another workbook and paste data.

Whenever I run the code Excel recalculates so the macro takes a long time to run. When I switch calculations to manual it runs instantly.

To deal with this I added the Application.Calculation lines to the code but whenever I run the macro Excel still recalculates.

I am a VBA novice so I would be grateful if someone could help with what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

```
    Sub CreateNewSheet()
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Worksheets.Add()
    .Name = Range("E3").Value
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Call CopyData
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub

Sub CopyData()
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Summary").Range("A22:J58").Copy
Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A:J").Font.Size = 10

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Because on every `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` it immediately re-calculates.

Comment: You are calling it twice too copydata handles the recalc from newsheet.  Maybe do `setting calc off` call procs `set calc on`